# Lambda fails to publish to SNS topic sometimes

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

My AWS Lambda fails to publish messages to an AWS SNS topic every now and then.

```
2020-03-09T08:02:42.520Z Could not publish on sns with error: NetworkingError: write EPROTO
2020-03-09T08:02:42.789Z Could not publish on sns with error: NetworkingError: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
2020-03-09T08:04:14.797Z Could not publish on sns with error: NetworkingError: connect EPIPE 54.239.55.119:443
```

I'm using `aws-sdk:2.632.0` on `Node v12.13.0`. It seems like those issues show up in blocks (like 10 in a row and then not a single issue for an hour).

The code itself is not very sophisticated:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const executionRegion = process.env.AWS_REGION

const sns = new AWS.SNS({
  region: executionRegion
})

async function publishMessage(message, topic) {
  const snsMessage = {
    Message: JSON.stringify(message),
    TopicArn: topic
  }
  try {
    winston.info(`publish sns message ${JSON.stringify(snsMessage)}`);
    return await sns.publish(snsMessage).promise()
  } catch (err) {
    winston.error(`Could not publish message on sns :${err}`)
    return null
  }
}
```

Any idea what I could try to identify the issue?

Comment: can you share your full code? Like how are using aws sdk and creating sns instance?

Comment: Sure thing. I've just added the code to the question.

Comment: Doesn't look anything wrong here. In one of the post it read the similar issue. They say try `{
      httpOptions: {
        agent: new https.Agent({
          secureProtocol: "TLSv1_method",
          ciphers: "ALL"
        })
      }
    }` adding while creating sns instance

Comment: It's working in 95% of the cases, which is why it is pretty difficult to nail down the issue. Thank you for the hint, I'll give that a try.

Comment: just checked - adding `httpOptions` did not help

Comment: Are you running the lambda in VPC? If yes, I strongly suspect something wrong with any of the subnets (not all since it works most of the time). Please check your route table entries for all the subnets that are attached to lambda if within VPC

Comment: Were you awaiting the call `publishMessage`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the necropost, but I had encountered this post and just wrapped up a debugging session with very similar reported behavior.  The issue was apparently that SNS was being dispatched too quickly to the AWS SNS endpoint and the JS aws-sdk client was failing as a result.  The specific network error included the following information:

```
..."errorMessage":"UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `sns.us-region-1.amazonaws.com' at port `undefined'. This service may not be available in the `us-region-1' region."...
..."errorType":"NetworkingError","errorMessage":"write EPROTO","code":"NetworkingError","message":"write EPROTO","errno":-71,"syscall":"write","region":"us-region-1","hostname":"sns.us-region-1.amazonaws.com"...
..."stack":["Error: write EPROTO"...
...Request.ENOTFOUND_ERROR...
```

The solution was to serialize the dispatching of the SNS in the JS code.  Async dispatch of a couple dozen SNS messages reliably caused the bug on our side.